# padding-bottom not showing up on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

When I'm using padding-bottom: 80px to reserve a blank space at the bottom of the page, with height 80px. This **works on Chrome**:
All pics are when you scroll to the very bottom.
[image]

But it **doesn't work on Firefox**:
[image]

The idea is that once you get to the bottom, a bottom-bar pops up (it's just hidden now with display: none;). This is the **proper render on Chrome**:
[image]

But it **doesn't work on Firefox**, and the bottom comes up to hide the bottom of the page (despite the padding!)
[image]

Any idea why this is happening? When I'm not having the bottom bar slide (i.e just render), it renders incorrectly, as in Firefox will hide the bottom part of the webpage with the bottom bar.

UPDATE with some relevant CSS:

```
.submissions-wrapper {
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  //border-bottom: 80px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.submission-bottom-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 298;
  padding: 10px 30px;

  background-color: #2a3333;
  border-top: 1px solid #0b0e10;

  .inverted-button,
  .flat-button {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 10px 60px;
  }

  display: none;
  //visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: `html, body {height: 100%}`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't quite work :/ Moreover I don't set the height to anything other than 100% anywhere.

Comment: It was a wild guess based on the almost nothing you've given us to go from. :-)

Comment: Haha yea this has a lot of components so I didn't want to spend too much time writing it out; the hacky fix is to add an empty div with the height as the padding I wanted (depending on the browser). The fix makes me cringe though...

Comment: The CSS for the primary layout elements and the bottom bar would probably be adequate. Your question is on the verge of being closed unless you improve it.

Comment: I ended up using a Gem on Server side that checked for the Browser and add an empty element, actually works rather well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm on Rails, I used the [Browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser) Gem to detect the browser (server side). Then I add an empty div for the browsers with the issue. This solution worked in 30 sec after 2 hours of dealing with css, so recommended if you're looking for a quick fix. Probably NOT the most efficient or elegant.

Sample code (will probably add other browsers after checking):

```
- if browser.firefox?
  .submission-bar-clone style="height: 80px"

.submission-bottom-bar.clearfix 
  / render the regular bar.
```